# How to split a <ul> with unequal <li> into 2 rows and display the <li> center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find anything that helped.

TLDR - I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/E9h2b/1/). I need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SkewerHed/E9h2b/) but only between (max-width:768px) and (min-width: 481px).

I have a fixed .navbar with justified navbar-nav links.

So what I need is that when the screen displays (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px) the links need to drop down into 2 rows.

There are only 7 links. Ideally I'd place 4 top and 3 bottom while having both rows' links perfectly centered.

The uneven number kind of messes me up, otherwise I'd not have a problem.

I tried to wrap the links like this:

```
#4links ul li {
    width: 25%;
}
#3links ul li {
    width: 33.333%
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/E9h2b/1/). I need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SkewerHed/E9h2b/) but only between (max-width:768px) and (min-width: 481px).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
    #4links ul li {
       width: 25%;
    }
    #3links ul li {
       width: 33.333%
    }
    #4links ul {
       width: 100%;
       float: left;
    }
    #3links ul {
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: I added your code but it just displays 2 rows at all widths. I added all my code and update the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkewerHed/E9h2b/) in my post.